# Best practice to generate a JPA dynamic, typed query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

i'm trying to convert a 'TableController'-Class we used (without ORM) to generate dynamic SQL (actually the order column and direction is appended to the SQL).

Think of this 'TableController' as a class that have a function to return a list of Entities of a given class (known at runtime), in a given order (String column/property name, boolean asc/desc, both at runtime).

The challenge is now, with JPA (Hibernate - but the customer requires to use JPA Interfaces only): How can i realize this without String concatenation, and in a type safe manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The challenge is now, with JPA (Hibernate - but the customer requires to use JPA Interfaces only): how can I realize this without String concatenation, and in a type safe manner?

If you're using a JPA 2.0 implementation, I think you should look at the [Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) to build dynamic queries.

If you're using JPA 1.0, there is no standard way apart from String concatenation (and my suggestion would be to use Hibernate's proprietary [Criteria Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)).

The following article might also give you some (concrete) ideas: [Hibernate Querying 102 : Criteria API](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery102/).

---

> Imagine a method that has three parameters: Class entityClass, String orderByColumn, boolean ascending. How would i create a query without string concatenation that gives me all objects of the given class in the correct order?

With the Criteria API from JPA 2.0, you could do something like this:

```
public <T> List<T> findAllEntitiesOrderedBy(Class<T> entityClass, String orderByColumn, boolean ascending) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(entityClass);
    Root<T> entityRoot = criteria.from(entityClass);
    criteria.select(entityRoot);
    javax.persistence.criteria.Order order = ascending ? builder.asc(entityRoot.get(orderByColumn))
        : builder.desc(entityRoot.get(orderByColumn));
    criteria.orderBy(order);
    return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Pascal - thank you for your suggestions. We use JPA 2.0 and i already thought it would lead us to the Criteria API. But how can i solve this particular problem i described?

Comment: Can't be more precise with the actual description of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for my delay - Imagine a method that has three parameters: Class entityClass, String orderByColumn, boolean ascending. How would i create a query without string concatenation that gives me all objects of the given class in the correct order? Thanks!

Comment: What about creating the order objects outside this method? :D Do you know if thiss even possible? I'm using a map right know and I didn't found smth like this